# Tufte-book problem with \ref

Tags: tufte, books

The first time I typeset this I get `??` for the `\ref`. The second time, it is blank. I am using TeXShop. I set out to make an example that uses `biblatex` to get a list of references for each chapter and another list at the end of the book. It makes the reference lists OK, but not the `\ref` marks. What is wrong?

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
 \chapter{First chapter}\label{ch01}
 \section{Foo}\label{ch01:sec01}
 Some text \citep{Duffie:96}.
 \section{Bee}
 Refer to \ref{ch01:sec01} of chapter \ref{ch01}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

 \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{Second chapter}
 \section{Bar}
 Some text\autocite{Eason1999}. 
 Remember section \ref{ch01:sec01} of chapter \ref{ch01} down here.
 \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
 \end{refsection}

\chapter{Later}
This,\autocite{hashemian} should be a side note but not this \citep{hashemian}.
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Here is references.bib:

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/


%% Created for Sam Cox at 2016-02-17 17:46:29 -0500 


%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



@book{Duffie:96,
    Address = {Princeton, NJ 08540},
    Author = {Duffie, J. Darrell},
    Date-Added = {2016-02-17 22:36:09 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-02-17 22:36:09 +0000},
    Edition = {2nd},
    Publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    Title = {Dynamic Asset Pricing Theory},
    Year = {1996}}

@article{Eason1999,
    Author = {Eason, Stephen W. and Hirst, Brian L. and Vukelic, Milan},
    Date-Added = {2016-02-17 22:35:52 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-02-17 22:35:52 +0000},
    Journal = {Record of the Society of Actuaries},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {1--20},
    Title = {Security Blanket for Life (and Health)},
    Volume = {25},
    Year = {1999}}

@book{childs_temperature,
    Address = {Great Britain},
    Author = {Childs, Peter R N},
    Edition = {1},
    Isbn = {0 7506 5080 X},
    Publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
    Title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
    Year = {2001}}

@phdthesis{hashemian,
    Author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
    School = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
    Title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
    Type = {PhD {T}hesis},
    Year = {2011}}
```

Answer (score 11):

The chapter and section headings are unnumbered in the `tufte-book` document class. Since `\ref` wants to print the chapter/section number and can't find it, it complains in the log file:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 18.
```

If you turn on the chapter and section numbering (by adding `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` to the preamble of your document), it should fix the problem.

Note, however, that the headings in the `tufte-book` aren't designed to print the numbering nicely by default, so you may need to fiddle with the formatting a little bit.

As an alternative, you might consider using `\nameref` instead of `\ref` to print the name of the chapter/section instead of the number.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved the problem. I am using \setcounter.

Comment: +1 for the `\nameref` suggestion. Just what I needed to know.