# Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link

Tags: hyperref

I am using SIGCHI Latex format at https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats

However, when I tried to refer to a label

```
We will discuss in Section \ref{my_label}

...

\section{bla bla} \label{my_label}
```

The warning as the title appeared and there is no number appear after the text `Section` at all. I think the problem is because I refer to the label before I define the label, but this problem does not appear with other proceeding formats.

Could you help me a bit?

Comment: are the sections numbered?  perhaps numbering is suppressed by that document class.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The sections are not numbered. In this case, what should I do to refer to a section?

Comment: you can put in an anchor for hyperref, but i don't remember the exact code, and i'm not able to test at the moment.  i'm sure this has been covered here -- search in the questions for "hyperref" and "anchor".

Comment: Hi, I am using ``nameref``, not good as before, but I am not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Add \newcounter{section} (if not already defined) in the preamble and put \refstepcounter{section} after \section and before \label.

Comment: This worked for me! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294534/tufte-book-problem-with-ref \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about referencing unnumbered sections and is solved in the comments.